# When creating annotation from labels is it possible to feature-link another annotation layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, arcgis-flex-api, annotation

I have an annotation layer that is currently being used in the flex viewer and I would like to add a secondary annotation layer/line so that it sits directly underneath the first.

I am able to link the new annotation layer to the polygon I am creating it from, but I wonder if there is a way to also link it to the annotation layer I already have; as I am having trouble getting the annotation to sit underneath the first one.

I tried setting the offset, but as it offsets from either the center or the edge of the block, the new annotation does not line up within the top right corner underneath the original annotation. Editing is off the table as I would have some 30,000 records to manipulate manually.

Is there any way to link these labels to the original annotation layer before I turn them into annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can Append the Annotation

**Append Annotation Feature Classes (Data Management)** [ArcEDITOR or ARCINFO License only]

Creates a new geodatabase annotation feature class or appends to an existing annotation feature class by combining annotation from multiple input geodatabase annotation feature classes into a single feature class with annotation classes.
Usage

```
When appending multiple annotation feature classes into a new annotation feature class, the input annotation feature classes must reside in the same database.

The output geodatabase annotation feature class cannot be registered as versioned.

If you select geodatabase annotation features in ArcMap or build a definition query, only those features will be appended to the output feature class.

When appending feature-linked annotation feature classes, all the input annotation feature classes must be linked to the same feature class.

If you select an output annotation feature class that already exists, the features will be appended to that feature class and the tool will project the annotation features in the destination spatial reference.

An ArcEditor or ArcInfo license is required to create an output annotation feature class that is feature-linked.
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000029000000.htm